# best algorithm to shuffle an array

Tags: algorithm, random, permutation, shuffle

I have a array s = {'ACA','BBC','CKA',...};

I want to shuffle s. So I create list A={1,2,3,4..} and list B={1,2,3,4,...}

Then, I shuffle the two lists.
random.shuffle(A)
random.shuffle(B)

finally, I swap s[A[0]] with s[B[0]], swap s[A[1]] with s[B[1]].....

Is this algorithm producing random permutation of s? Is it random enough? Assuming random.shuffle produces random enough permutations of A and B.

Comment: What language is this? Why can't you just shuffle your original array instead of creating two other arrays, shuffling them, then using that to shuffle the first?

Comment: What is relation of s,A and B.  Your question seems telling insufficient parts of several problems.

Comment: s is a very large sequence of strings. each string is about 8000 bytes. A and B are permutations of sequence {1,2,3,....length(s)}

Comment: @NickT I am using C language. each element of s is actually very long string (about 8000 bytes). s is about 500GB, I want to do in-place permutation of s, since I want to keep every thing in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Fisher--Yates (Knuth) shuffle with an index array, initialize a single index array `A` like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) A[i] = /* random integer in 0..i */;
```

and then do swaps like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) swap(&s[A[i]], &s[i]);
```

Your algorithm does not generate uniform random permutations. When n = 2, the possibilities for A and B are

```
A = {0, 1}; B = {0, 1};
A = {0, 1}; B = {1, 0};
A = {1, 0}; B = {0, 1};
A = {1, 0}; B = {1, 0};
```

None of these have any effect on the starting permutation; either both elements are swapped with themselves, or the same nontrivial swap is repeated twice, undoing its effect.

Comment: I think your code works very well. But I am very curious about if my algorithm generates uniform random permutation. I am hoping someone can give mathematical justification.

Comment: @readRead It doesn't work; when n = 2, nothing ever gets moved in the final accounting.

Answer (score 2):

[Knut's shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is simple and effecitive method to shuffle an array. You don't need additional index arrays. Is there any special reason for their using?

Comment: Does Knut's shuffle produce more random permutation than my algorithm? I use index arrays because I want to permute another array x in the exactly same way. s and x has one to one correspondence.

Comment: It just produces uniform distribution (all the permutations have equal probabilities)